# How to make an ftp remote with rclone

Tags: ftp, rclone

I'm trying to sync an ftp server with a google cloud bucket. I think the easiest way to do this is with rclone.

According to the docs, [rclone can link up to ftp easily](https://rclone.org/ftp/). However, when running it myself, the output I get is very different:

```
e/n/d/r/c/s/q> n
name> remote_ftp
Type of storage to configure.
Choose a number from below, or type in your own value
 1 / Amazon Drive
   \ "amazon cloud drive"
 2 / Amazon S3 (also Dreamhost, Ceph, Minio)
   \ "s3"
 3 / Backblaze B2
   \ "b2"
 4 / Dropbox
   \ "dropbox"
 5 / Encrypt/Decrypt a remote
   \ "crypt"
 6 / Google Cloud Storage (this is not Google Drive)
   \ "google cloud storage"
 7 / Google Drive
   \ "drive"
 8 / Hubic
   \ "hubic"
 9 / Local Disk
   \ "local"
10 / Microsoft OneDrive
   \ "onedrive"
11 / Openstack Swift (Rackspace Cloud Files, Memset Memstore, OVH)
   \ "swift"
12 / SSH/SFTP Connection
   \ "sftp"
13 / Yandex Disk
   \ "yandex"
```

As you can see, there is no option listed for ftp, and when I copy the example I simply get the error:

> Failed to find remote: didn't find filing system for "ftp"

I suspect I'm missing something very obvious. How do I add a new remote for an ftp server on rclone?

I'm using rclone v1.36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing the beta version:

```
curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | sudo bash -s beta
```

This lists all the following as possible remotes:

```
1 / 1Fichier
   \ "fichier"
 2 / Alias for an existing remote
   \ "alias"
 3 / Amazon Drive
   \ "amazon cloud drive"
 4 / Amazon S3 Compliant Storage Provider (AWS, Alibaba, Ceph, Digital Ocean, Dreamhost, IBM COS, Minio, etc)
   \ "s3"
 5 / Backblaze B2
   \ "b2"
 6 / Box
   \ "box"
 7 / Cache a remote
   \ "cache"
 8 / Dropbox
   \ "dropbox"
 9 / Encrypt/Decrypt a remote
   \ "crypt"
10 / FTP Connection
   \ "ftp"
11 / Google Cloud Storage (this is not Google Drive)
   \ "google cloud storage"
12 / Google Drive
   \ "drive"
13 / Google Photos
   \ "google photos"
14 / Hubic
   \ "hubic"
15 / JottaCloud
   \ "jottacloud"
16 / Koofr
   \ "koofr"
17 / Local Disk
   \ "local"
18 / Mail.ru Cloud
   \ "mailru"
19 / Mega
   \ "mega"
20 / Microsoft Azure Blob Storage
   \ "azureblob"
21 / Microsoft OneDrive
   \ "onedrive"
22 / OpenDrive
   \ "opendrive"
23 / Openstack Swift (Rackspace Cloud Files, Memset Memstore, OVH)
   \ "swift"
24 / Pcloud
   \ "pcloud"
25 / Put.io
   \ "putio"
26 / QingCloud Object Storage
   \ "qingstor"
27 / SSH/SFTP Connection
   \ "sftp"
28 / Union merges the contents of several remotes
   \ "union"
29 / Webdav
   \ "webdav"
30 / Yandex Disk
   \ "yandex"
31 / http Connection
   \ "http"
32 / premiumize.me
   \ "premiumizeme"
```

Comment: Thanks!  The curl command hung on me for some reason but the Ubuntu repos have a rclone-dev version which worked the same way.